# running Docker as a Conemu task

Tags: docker, conemu

I am trying to make docker run on ConEmu by creating a task that open up Docker `start.sh` file using `git bash`.

Since normally docker Terminal is pointing to `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"` ,is there any way I can make a task on ConEmu to do this? So something like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like this question on superuser has some information; http://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu

Comment: @thaJeztah doesn't seem so related

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1027790/docker-on-conemu

Comment: check the answer posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1027790/docker-on-conemu/1028606#1028606)

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps, I followed to create docker console in conemu:

- Go to "Settings" menu.
- Select "Startup > Tasks"
- Click on "+" button to add new task.
- Provide name as "docker"
- Set value text area with
   "-new_console:d:C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox" "%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"

Here is the screenshot:
[Docker task settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KDe2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration:

Task parameters:

```
/dir "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox"
```

Command:

```
"%ConEmuDrive%\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-quickstart-terminal.ico" "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
```